# Code does not catch FormatException in C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, formatexception

I have the following method in the class `ProductServices`:

```
public bool IsDownloadAllowed(int Id, string productId)
{
  if (CustomStringFunctions.IsGuid(productId))
  {
     //Do Something
  }
  else
  {
     throw new FormatException("The Guid must be a valid Guid!");
  }
}
```

If I use the method in the following set of instructions:

```
var _productServices = new ProductServices();
try
{
   var flag = _productServices.IsDownloadAllowed(Id, productId);
   //do something
}

catch (Exception e)
{
   //handle exception
}
```

The exception is not caught by the `catch` statement. I also tried to replace `Exception` with `FormatException` with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in and go step by step?

Comment: Avoid writing custom functions for functionality already available in .NET.  Use the Guid(string) constructor, it throws a FormatException

Comment: Yes you are right but I try to avoid using exception as much as possible for performance reason. I prefer to use if-else when I can

Comment: @CiccioMiami in general it's good to avoid using exceptions for control flow, but if the "else" branch of the code is simply throwing an exception, there's no point!  It will perform better if you just let the framework throw the exception.  If you're using a recent enough version of the framework, the preferred way to avoid using exceptions for flow control would be to use Guid.TryParse.

Comment: so this way I should put the Guid.TryParse in a try-catch block, catch the FormatException and throw it again for the calling function?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of productId you are passing into the function is _not_ a guid?

Comment: of course, I evaluate it step by step

Comment: @phoog I tried TryParse and it consider as Guid also the string.empty. Now I remember why I chose a custom solution

Comment: @CiccioMiami There's no point in using TryParse in a try-catch block, since TryParse does not throw.  The point of TryParse is to avoid having an exception altogether.  In any event, the proper handling of an invalid string depends on why the string is invalid and what should be done when the string is invalid.  But that's a digression from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You must have mute exception in this code

```
if (CustomStringFunctions.IsGuid(productId))
  {
     //Do Something
  }
```

You must be sure that you throw exception when occured (In the Do Something)

Sample of mute exception

```
Try
{

}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
   //throw don't exist
}
```

Comment: I checked the code in debug mode and there is no exception...I want to throw the exception if CustomStringFunctions.IsGuid(productId) returns false

Comment: if(! CustomStringFunctions.IsGuid(productId)) {throw new CustomException("custom messaage");} , you can define custom exception , but with this strategy you must manage referentiel and doc about exception.

Comment: You can also just throw new Exception

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct.  A possible explanation for your problem is that `CustomStringFunctions.IsGuid` is incorrectly returning `true`, so the `\\do something` branch is executing instead of the exception-throwing branch.